# how to use for loop for functions

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

hope you all doing well. I am making a "Rock Paper Scissors" game for 'TheOdinProject', I completed it but here is the problem with loop, when I use it for console it works fine, and when calling a function its not looping. sorry for the bad english.
The last function `game()` is for looping, please help me to find the problem. thanks in advance.

```
function getComputerChoice() {
    const gameChoice = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor'];
    const randomChoice = gameChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameChoice.length)];
    // console.log(randomChoice);
    return randomChoice;
}
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    switch (true) {
        case (playerSelection === computerSelection):
            return console.log('Game Tie, please try again.');
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissor'):
            let greetingRock = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            return console.log(`${greetingRock} You Win, Rock beats the scissor`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper'):
            let courageRock = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            return console.log(`${courageRock} You Lose, Paper beats the Rock`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'scissor' && computerSelection === 'rock'):
            let courageScissor = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            return console.log(`${courageScissor} You Lose, Rock beats the scissor`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'scissor' && computerSelection === 'paper'):
            let greetingScissor = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            return console.log(`${greetingScissor} You Win, Scissor beats the Paper`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors'):
            let couragePaper = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            return console.log(`${couragePaper} You Lose, Scissor beats the Paper`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock'):
            let greetingPaper = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            return console.log(`${greetingPaper} You Win, Paper beats the Rock`);
            break;
    }
}
let userValue = prompt('Choose your Item:', '').toLowerCase();
if( userValue == null || userValue == "") {
    prompt('Please Choose one of: Rock, Paper, scissor')
}
const playerSelection = userValue;
const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
// console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection))


function game() {
    for ( let i = 0; i < 5; i++ ) {
        let playAgain = playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        return playAgain;
    }
}
game();
// console.log(game());
```

```
function getComputerChoice() {
    const gameChoice = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor'];
    const randomChoice = gameChoice[Math.floor(Math.random() * gameChoice.length)];
    // console.log(randomChoice);
    return randomChoice;
}
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection) {
    switch (true) {
        case (playerSelection === computerSelection):
            console.log('Game Tie, please try again.');
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'scissor'):
            let greetingRock = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            console.log(`${greetingRock} You Win, Rock beats the scissor`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'rock' && computerSelection === 'paper'):
            let courageRock = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            console.log(`${courageRock} You Lose, Paper beats the Rock`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'scissor' && computerSelection === 'rock'):
            let courageScissor = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            console.log(`${courageScissor} You Lose, Rock beats the scissor`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'scissor' && computerSelection === 'paper'):
            let greetingScissor = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            console.log(`${greetingScissor} You Win, Scissor beats the Paper`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'scissors'):
            let couragePaper = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            console.log(`${couragePaper} You Lose, Scissor beats the Paper`);
            break;
        case (playerSelection === 'paper' && computerSelection === 'rock'):
            let greetingPaper = `You Choose: ${playerSelection} and`;
            console.log(`${greetingPaper} You Win, Paper beats the Rock`);
            break;
    }
}

function getPlayerChoice() {
    const userValue = prompt('Choose your Item:', '').toLowerCase();
    if (userValue == null || userValue == '') {
        prompt('Please choose one of: Rock, Paper, Scissor');
    }
    const playerSelection = userValue;
    const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
}

function game() {
    let playAgain;
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        playAgain = getPlayerChoice();
    }
}
game()
```

Comment: Here's a hint, what does `return` do? I think you need to re read the explanation of what it does, because the way you are currently using it makes very little sense.

Comment: You also need to move everything from `let userValue = ...` till `const computerSelection = getComputerChoice();` inside your for loop or you will get five identical games (provided you've removed the `return` line that exits the function after one game)

Comment: thanks guys: NickBailey, ChrisG, maybe I got it.
now I am modifying it...

Comment: new one is edit below the question. it works very well. thanks again.